# Meteor js using webservices SOAP using package zardak/soap

Tags: javascript, web-services, meteor, soap, wsdl

I am new to js and even newer to meteor. I am having some troubles using a simple function to post data to a wsdl for a function call and return response. I am using a package in meteor - zardak/soap and I am able to create the client and get a result without an error so Im assuming some of my code is good but the response Im getting back is -1 no matter the values I use in args. I am really hoping someone with more exp than me will take time out their life to help me with this. Please and thanks, below is my meteor method call:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'testwsdl' () {
   var url = 'http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl';
   var args = {
     FromCurrency: 'USD',
     ToCurrency: 'INR'
   };

   try {
     var client = Soap.createClient(url);
     var result = client.ConversionRate(args);
     console.log(result);
   } catch (err) {
     if (err.error === 'soap-creation') {
       console.log('SOAP Client creation failed');
     } else if (err.error === 'soap-method') {
       console.log('SOAP Method call failed');
     }

   }
   return result;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also discussed here:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91292/currency-rate-not-importing-correctly-from-webservicex

You're not doing anything wrong with the zardak/soap library. This service is just not correctly returning values.

Try hitting this endpoint and invoking the Test section with some values (such as USD and EUR):

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?op=ConversionRate

You'll see that you always get -1.0 as a value. Try using a different web service endpoint.